# MERGE leads to 'Subquery returned more than 1 value' error in trigger

Tags: sql-server-2008, triggers, merge, sql-update

Below is the trigger that is on the table and the query I am using for updating.

**Trigger**

*This trigger will update a Type ID column based on the text inserted or updated into another column...This is to force typing on a badly designed table*

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TypeIDInsert] 
    ON [dbo].[Table1]
    AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN

    IF (SELECT TypeID FROM inserted) IS NULL
    BEGIN

        DECLARE @ID [int] = (SELECT ID FROM inserted);

        UPDATE Table1 SET TypeID = (
            CASE TypeName
                WHEN 'Value 1' THEN 1
                WHEN 'Value 2' THEN 2
                WHEN 'Value 3' THEN 3
                ELSE 0
            END
        )
        WHERE ID = @ID

    END

END
```

The `ID` column is an `IDENTITY` column.

**Update Statement**

```
MERGE INTO Table1
    USING Table1TypeTable
        ON Table1.TypeName= TypeTable.TypeName
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET TypeID = TypeTable.TypeID;
```

When the trigger is enabled I get the error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

I found this post [Update statement error: Subquery returned more than 1 value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660755/update-statement-error-subquery-returned-more-than-1-value) describing that the issue is the trigger on the table was designed for only one record at a time. I disabled the trigger and was able to successfully do the update. My question is how to write the trigger as to not cause an issue on a mass update like this.

Comment: Yikes, your trigger assumes that all operations only affect one row!

Comment: I see that, what would be the best way to reformat this trigger to not assume?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things: your trigger assumed that all operations only affect one row. The way to do this is to *join* to the inserted table, instead of trying to stuff a single variable with the ID value from who knows what row. Also the check against `inserted` (which in your example is missing `EXISTS`) is not really necessary. If there are 0 rows in `inserted` the update won't be performed anyway.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[TypeIDInsert] 
    ON [dbo].[Table1]
    AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  UPDATE t SET t.TypeID = CASE i.TypeName
      WHEN 'Value 1' THEN 1
      WHEN 'Value 2' THEN 2
      WHEN 'Value 3' THEN 3
      ELSE 0 END
    FROM dbo.Table1 AS t
    INNER JOIN inserted AS i
    ON t.ID = i.ID;
END
GO
```